# How to call destructor of singleton classes without CRT

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crt

I am developing a program without the C runtime library (CRT) with C++ as a fun little challenge. As part of this challenge I ended up writing my own `atexit()` function which is called whenever `main` returns.

This function [works as expected](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) and calls the destructor of most classes, with a caveat: I have to manually run all destructor functions (they are stored in a linked list, and executed in a last-in, first-out (LIFO) order) before my main function terminates. If anybody knows a better way, do let me know, but that's a separate issue.

My main problem is that while debugging, I found out that the destructor of my singleton classes are not being called, and I'm trying to figure out why. I am new to C++, please don't bully me.

Code example of singleton:

```cpp
/*socket_manager.h*/
class SocketManager {
    // static instance variable here
    static SocketManager* instance;
    ~SocketManager() {
        // close socket/do cleanup, this is what I'm trying to get to run
     }

public:
    static SocketManager* getInstance();
}


/*socket_manager.cpp*/

// global variable for instance, set to nullptr
SocketManager* SocketManager::instance = nullptr;

// creates new SocketManager if instance is null, else returns instance
SocketManager *SocketManager::getInstance() {
    if (instance == nullptr) {
        instance = new SocketManager();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Essentially: What am I doing wrong? How do I make sure the destructor for this singleton is executed on program termination, without the STL/CRT?

Comment: `deconstructor` -- The term is *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Comment: If you have a singleton (should be rare) then do NOT use `new` use the "Meyer's singleton" pattern. `static SocketManager getInstance() { static SocketManager mrg; return mgr};`. This will ensure your singleton gets destructed when you app shutsdown. Also you do know `new/delete` are hardly used anymore in current C++ are you? Have a look at std::make_unique too

Comment: However you really should learn to make designs that do NOT rely on singletons at all.  Make an abstract baseclass for your manager (interface), create an instance in main and pass the interface around to the pieces of code that need access to it. Lookup dependency injection (and unit testability) and forget singletons ever existed (until you really know when, where and why you have an exceptional case)

Comment: If you `new` _anything_ and store a raw pointer, it is never cleaned up automatically. It doesn't matter whether this is a singleton or not. Your class isn't a singleton anyway. Not only is there a race condition on `getInstance`, but there's nothing to stop anyone from constructing multiple `SocketManager` instances and never call that function if they want to.

Comment: You've shown us your singleton implementation, which is an important element of your scenario (and of your [mre]). However, you did not show us the code that is misbehaving, the `atexit` function that is supposed to call `~SocketManager`. Without seeing this, the best answer you can reasonably hope for is "there's a bug in your code".

Comment: A "normal" program linked with the C++ runtime library would not have called `~SocketManager` destructor either. What is `new`ed should be `delete`d.

Comment: *"without the STL/CRT"* -- I was able to deduce "CRT" from the question's tags, but I'm a little stuck on STL. I'm pretty sure you mean one of the last two "typical intended meanings" listed on [the stl tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) (the incorrect meanings), but which one? Are you avoiding just the templates of the C++ standard library, or are you avoiding the entire C++ standard library? (Probably the latter? Since you are not using [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit)?)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. It looks like I had a misunderstanding of how `new` worked, which cleared it up for me. I've migrated my code to the "Meyer singleton" pattern mentioned by Pepijin and confirmed that everything worked the way I wanted it to.